# Como eu posso alterar o estilo de uma tag html usando outra tag html no css?

Tags: html, css, menu, css-hover, elementos

Então povo eu estou fazendo um menu e queria descartar o uso de javascript com isso gostaria de fazer com que quando eu pressionasse o mouse encima do ícone menu automaticamente o meu elemento #content ganhasse uma margin-top: 320px, olhem meu código:

```
///* CSS *///

#content{
     margin-top: 50px
}

#menu img:hover + #content{
     margin-top: 320px;
}

///* HTML *///
<div id="menu"> 

     <img src="image.png">

</div>

<div id="content">

     <hr>

</div>
```

Comment: Cara se vc tem que pressionar no ícone para ele abrir, como vc vai tirar o mouse do ícone para clicar na opção do menu? Assim que vc tirar o mouse do ícone o menu vai fechar e vc não vai conseguir clicar nos itens do menu....

Comment: Acho que vai ter que usar javascript.

Answer (score 0):

O seletor + só pode ser utilizado para selecionar um elemento que venha logo abaixo, e como a imagem está dentro da div `#menu`, o uso do seletor está incorreto. O que você pode fazer modificar o código para esse aqui

```
#content{
    margin-top: 50px
}
            
#menu:hover ~ #content{
    margin-top:320px;
}
```

Comment: Ele não quer no hover foi só um exemplo ele quer ao clicar.

Comment: Então ele só vai poder alcançar o resultado usando jquery ou javascript

Answer (score -4):

O selector `:hover` aplica estilos quando o mouse passa por cima do elemeto, para aplicar estilos quando um elemento é pressionado é preciso usar o seletor `:focus` no seu caso ficaria:

```
#content:focus {
  margin-top: 320px;
}
```

Comment: Não é verdade que a pseudo classe `:focus` é aplicada quando um elemento é clicado. A pseudo classe `:focus` é aplicada quando um elemento é selecionado, independente de ser selecionado por mouse ou por teclado. Veja o [exemplo](https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/zYNmJZv).

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, não sabia que bastava o elemento estar selecionado com a tecla tab para ativar o :focus